# Pandas DataFrame convert to binary

Tags: python, pandas

Given `pd.DataFrame` with `0.0 < values < 1.0`, I would like to convert it to binary values `0` /`1` according to defined threshold `eps = 0.5`,

```
      0     1     2
0  0.35  0.20  0.81
1  0.41  0.75  0.59
2  0.62  0.40  0.94
3  0.17  0.51  0.29
```

Right now, I only have this `for loop` which takes quite long time for large dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.array([[.35, .2, .81],[.41, .75, .59],
                [.62, .4, .94], [.17, .51, .29]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=range(data.shape[0]), columns=range(data.shape[1]))
eps = .5
b = np.zeros((df.shape[0], df.shape[1]))
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for j in range(df.shape[1]):
        if df.loc[i,j] < eps:
            b[i,j] = 0
        else:
            b[i,j] = 1
df_bin = pd.DataFrame(b, columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
```

Does anybody know a more effective way to convert to binary values?

```
     0    1    2
0  0.0  0.0  1.0
1  0.0  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  0.0  1.0
3  0.0  1.0  0.0
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### `df.round`

```
>>> df.round()
```

#### `np.round`

```
>>> np.round(df)
```

#### `astype`

```
>>> df.ge(0.5).astype(int)
```

All which yield

```
     0    1    2
0  0.0  0.0  1.0
1  0.0  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  0.0  1.0
3  0.0  1.0  0.0
```

---

Note: `round` works here because it automatically sets the threshold for `.5` between two integers. For custom thresholds, use the 3rd solution

Answer (score 8):

Or you can use [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and assign the values to the underlying array:

```
df[:]=np.where(df<0.5,0,1)
```

---

```
   0  1  2
0  0  0  1
1  0  1  1
2  1  0  1
3  0  1  0
```

Answer (score 4):

Since we have a quite a some answers, which are all using different methods, I was curious about the speed comparison. Thought I share:

```
# create big test dataframe
dfbig = pd.concat([df]*200000, ignore_index=True)
print(dfbig.shape)

(800000, 3)
```

```
# pandas round()
%%timeit 
dfbig.round()

101 ms ± 4.63 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

```
# numpy round()
%%timeit
np.round(dfbig)

104 ms ± 2.71 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

```
# pandas .ge & .astype
%%timeit
dfbig.ge(0.5).astype(int)

9.32 ms ± 170 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```
# numpy.where
%%timeit
np.where(dfbig<0.5, 0, 1)

21.5 ms ± 421 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

**Conlusion**:

1. pandas `ge` & `astype`
2. `np.where`
3. `np.round`
4. pandas `round`